# I get an error 0xc0000005 at boot up and when I try to open a program

Tags: windows-7

Good afternoon

So when my laptop starts up I get this error box several times: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application."

I get the same error whenever I try to open a program, like Chrome, Opera, Skype, antivirus programs. Internet Explorer opens, but it closes itself straight after.

I tried a Clean Boot, but with no luck.

Worth to notice is that yesterday at shutting down some windows updates were installed and today I started getting this error after the windows updates were configured at boot up.

What should I do ? Anyone has a fix to this issue?

Comment: If you are unable to launch an application it means your Windows installation is corrupt an/or you are infect with malware.  The updates installed are unlikely the cause of the corruption unless their installation was intrrupted.

Comment: Laptop worked fine the over day , so there must be something that triggered the problem.

Comment: You can try a system restore!

Comment: As I was thinking the updates caused the problem. 

I have deleted all the Windows Security Updates made the day before and the computer works fine now.

The DEP update embedded in one of the Security updates was causing all the application with pieces of random coding to be viewed as threats and blocked from opening.

Comment: Good job. Add that as an answer below so future visitors can see what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an issue with the Update [KB2859537](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2859537) which was released at this patchday. Post in the topic in the MS Answers forum:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/kb2859537-bsod/2787e746-cea2-41ae-b2fc-c2979c1c03e1

and hope for some help and remove the Updates as a workaround.

Comment: I tried to uninstall it with `wusa /uninstall /kb:2859537` but that update seems not to be installed on my machine. a friend deinstalled KB2872339 and it worked, but at my computer it didn't

Comment: MS has pulled the update after several users reported issues. So you have a different problem.