# Access violation error (0xc0000005) whenever I try to open any program

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem with my ASUS laptop (Windows 7 x64 Home Premium), where whenever I try to start any program (`cmd.exe`, `explorer.exe`, and various tools in control panel still work, but any 3rd party .exe files, `iexplore.exe`, MS Office apps - don't) - it crashes instantly with the following error message:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application.
```

That error code, as far as I know, stands for `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. And the problem started after windows update on (2016-Feb-10).

I am posting here as a last resort, since no matter how I tried to resolve this issue - it didn't work. The only remaining action would be complete reinstall, and I am trying to avoid that if possible.

---

What I tried:

- Running `sfc /scannow` command in command prompt, since I've read that it might fix corrupted windows files. It found everything to be in order.
- Running `memtest` (3 passes), since I've read that it might be an issue related to RAM failing. I doubted that it would find something, since the issues were related to non-essential, for Windows execution, applications, and I wasn't getting any BSODs. It didn't find any issues either.
- Then, I thought that there may be some kind of virus infecting the computer. So, I created a Live Rescue USB stick with antivirus scanner on it, and booted the laptop from it, and ran full hard drive, In-Depth scan. No infected files detected.
- Then, I thought that there may be issues with hard drive itself. So I ran `chkdsk C: /F /R`. No issues.
- Then, I wanted to check S.M.A.R.T records of the hard drive, to see if it is failing. I downloaded a portable app which can check that. And then I realized that I can't run it, since it crashes, on startup like any other app. Then, I boot to safe mode, where, apparently, everything works fine, and applications don't crash on startup. But still, no issues reported in S.M.A.R.T records.
- Then I tried to use tools such as `Process Monitor` to figure out what is happening before the applications crash. It had the same problem as any other application.
- Then I tried to run `System Restore` to restore to a point before those updates. After doing the restore, and a reboot of a laptop, it said that it wasn't able to complete the process to to the error code `0x80070005` which stands for `General access denied error`, so it is more or less the same as the original error.
- I started googling again, and found [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly/bbb9c037-77b3-4fae-93b9-ded70f7f9a17). But, since my Windows boot loader path doesn't contain `xOsload.exe`, but rather `winload.efi`, I assumed that it wouldn't help in my case.
- Then, I saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/632243/i-get-an-error-0xc0000005-at-boot-up-and-when-i-try-to-open-a-program). And, seeing that it is 2.5 years old, I didn't put much hope into it. I was right, after uninstalling the update in question, nothing changed.

So, I will be waiting on tips on how to solve this problem, without full reinstall (since that is, truly, the last resort). Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use a rescue disk to run one of the problematic programs from the computer's hard drive? I still suspect malware.

Comment: @BenN Well that rescue disc is an "ESET Live Rescue" installed on USB stick, which contains a Linux based OS. So, when booting from it, it doesn't boot to Windows, so I can't run any Windows .exe files from there. I can just scan those partitions. In addition, I could run several of programs just fine from the safe mode, while they would refuse to launch from regular boot.

Comment: When did this start? After a recent windows update?

Comment: @Moab Yes, it start after a windows update couple days back.

Comment: Boot into the Windows recovery environment and do a Windows System Restore, pick the restore point date labeled with the last windows updates being installed. If it boots now you will have to determine with specific windows update cased the issue, do this by installing updates one at a time and reboot, when you get that error again you have found the problematic update, do another system restore, then hide that particular update in windows update.

Comment: @Moab Well, at first, I didn't know how could I boot into windows recovery environment, because choosing "Repair Computer" option from F8 menu (the same menu where you can boot into safe mode) booted into ASUS recovery wizard, rather than Windows one, and I didn't have the Windows .iso file to turn into bootable USB (since there are no CDROM drive in that laptop).

Comment: @Moab  I, then, found [this tutorial](http://ccm.net/faq/29462-windows-7-create-a-system-repair-usb-key) on how to create bootable USB stick, but even then, when booting into it, and choosing repair option, it said that version of Windows on this USB, was mismatched to the one that is on my laptop. It was then, when I realized that I could still run the system recovery from the safe mode. And after that, I managed to pinpoint the problematic updates, which were: KB3126587, KB3126593.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the exact same issues after the february 9 security updates hit my x64 Windows 7. Managed to narrow the issue down to update 3126587, just deleted it from command prompt and I'm no longer getting the xc0000005's.

So in command prompt, just enter:
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:3126587

You could also delete the update using windows updater in safe mode, the updater wouldn't show the list of installed updates for me in normal mode.

Hope that helps!

Comment: well, at first, after following your answer, and removing the update, you mentioned, I still had this problem. So, I proceeded on installing the updates one by one, to figure out which one was, really, the issue, since it seemed that the one that was a problem for you, wasn't for me. And it turned out, that there was not one, but two updates that were causing the issue. One of them being the one you mentioned, and the other being KB3126593.